# How to make config file in Golang elegantly?

Tags: go, redis, config

I'm a newbie with Golang.
I want to write a program to manage my Redis instances so that I can create a Redis connection with specific config file. But I don't know how to create the config file for Redis instances elegantly.

I found "text/template" before, is that a good idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle configuration in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465705/how-to-handle-configuration-in-go)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Redis configuration files](http://redis.io/topics/config) have a simple text format. You can generate a configuration file using the fmt package:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "pidfile %s\n", pidFile)
fmt.Fprintf(w, "port %d\n", port)
```

where `w` is `io.Writer` for the output.

The text/template package is also a viable option. Given the template

```
pidfile {{.PidFile}}
port {{.Port}}
```

you can execute it with

```
t.Execute(w, map[string]interface{}{
   "PidFile": pidFile,
   "Port": port,
})
```

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the file format you want to support for those configs.

One library able to read most of those format (from a simple ini file to a JSON one) would be [**spf13/viper**](https://github.com/spf13/viper):

> Viper is a complete configuration solution for go applications. It has been designed to work within an application to handle all types of configuration. It supports
>
> - setting defaults
> - reading from yaml, toml and json config files
> - reading from environment variables
> - reading from remote config systems (Etcd or Consul)
> - reading from command line flags
> - setting explicit values

Comment: Your viper link is broken, but that library looks pretty cool. +1 for sharing

Comment: @Lander I fixed link.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a config file for development, testing, staging and production, I would recommend to use the `// +build` possibility offered by Go.

---

### Set up your Go program

You create 4 files in a `config` packages as followed :

```
src/program/config
               |
               |--config_dev.go
               |--config_test.go
               |--config_staging.go
               |--config_prod.go
```

---

### In the config files

Then in each file, you define the tag used to use that file during the `go build` (or run, ...) process.

It means for instance in *config_dev.go* :

```
// +build dev

package config

// Development ready configuration const based on the build tags.
const (
    MYSETTINGS = "dev blablabla"
    ISREADY    = false
)
```

In the *config_test.go*, that would look like :

```
// +build test

package config

// Development ready configuration const based on the build tags.
const (
    MYSETTINGS = "test blablabla"
    ISREADY    = true
)
```

---

Note the `// +build dev` and `// +build test`.

That are the tags you are going to use during build to tell which config file you want to use.

In any other Go file, you just have to call `config.ISREADY` without importing anything else that `"config"` in your file.

---

### Build

Then to build your app, you just have to run :

`go build -tags dev` to build with the *development config*

or

`go build -tags test` to build with the *testing config*.

Answer (score 1):

As redis config file has very simple structure I'd suggest you to look at encoding/csv package with Reader.Comma delimiter set just to blank space. It allow you to both read, parse and write configuration easily. Seems to me "slaveof {{.Host}} {{.Port}}" as template looks not very handy. But it's sure correct approach. Just  matter of taste.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use some configuration library. I like [Viper](http://spf13.com/project/viper) for is completeness.