# Handling configurations without defining explicit type objects

Tags: go, configuration

I am following the [solution (accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465705/how-to-handle-configuration-in-go) given here as to load configuration values in Go.
So far so good.

However, I want to use standard configuration load functions across different modules of the application and for simplicity and ease of it I am trying to achieve loading configurations without explicitly defining a customer object such as  `type Configuration struct`.

Because each configuration file would be different and I don't want to define multiple structs and structs everywhere and then change them when a new value is added/deleted in the configurations.

I might be unfair to compare but I am looking for which in python would be just like this:

```
//in config.py
ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD'

//in main.py
import config
...
if config.ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD':
...
```

Is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `map[string]string` type if all your config values are strings or a `map[string]interface{}` type if you need arbitrary value types.

Although `map[string]interface{}` is a bit more cumbersome and a bit less safe, because you can cast `interface{}` to any type.

Here is a guide for using `map[string]interface{}`: https://bitfieldconsulting.com/golang/map-string-interface